# Batch script to zip like files using wildcard

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a folder with 600 text files, I'm looking to zip together files with similar identifiers. So for instance I have 10 files with id001~ as the identifier, those 10 will be zipped in the same directory and so forth. So far I have a code that will zip 1 file when you hard code the file name. I'm not sure if this should read off a list or maybe specify some type of wildcard criteria for which files to zip

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
echo off
set archievePatch=id001~testfile3.txt
7z.exe a %archievepatch%.zip "%archievePatch%" 

PATH :\Users\Jeffery\Desktop\TestFolder
pause
exit
```

This will output a zip file named: id001~testfile3.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that one sample of how your filename looks like the following script would group all files together in a zip file as long as the first 5 characters are equal.

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b /on *.txt') do call :onefile %%f

goto :eof

:onefile
set arg1=%1

rem here is the number of characters configured that form a group
set grp=%arg1:~0,5%

call :zipit %arg1% %grp%
goto :EOF

:zipit
rem remove echo when done debugging
echo 7z.exe a "%2.zip" "%1"
goto :EOF
```

This would create a file `id001.zip` with all files that start with `id001` like `id001~testfile3.txt` etc.

#### How does this work?

From the `help set` (or `SET /?`) pages:

> ...
>   May also specify substrings for an expansion.
>   `%PATH:~10,5%`
>   would expand the PATH environment variable, and then use only the 5
>   characters that begin at the 11th (offset 10) character of the expanded
>   result.  If the length is not specified, then it defaults to the
>   remainder of the variable value.
>   ...

The dir command accepts a `/b` argument to list files in bare-format and `/o` let you specify an order, the `n` means order alphabetically on filename.